# Regular Expression Phone Number and Phone Extension

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regular expression that cleans up phone numbers and turns them into valid phones numbers as such: +1 123-1223.

Regular Expression:

```
Regex.Replace(phone, @"^\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*$", "+1 $1$2$3-$4$5$6-$7$8$9$10");
```

But I would like to add on to it so anything over 12 numbers would add the remaining numbers as an extension. So If the number is 810.232.122323 it would become +1 810-232-1223 x23.

Is this possible by changing the regular expression? Is there a good way to do this? I don't know regular expressions all that well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this to the end, it will be your 11th group (and it will not pick up the extension unless it actually has 2 digits or more

```
(\d{2,})
```

The code will be:

```
Regex.Replace(phone, 
    @"^\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d{2,})$", 
    "+1 $1$2$3-$4$5$6-$7$8$9$10 Ext $11");
```

If this is to be optional, then do this:

```
(\d{2,})?
```

It will still match your phone numbers, but will not force an extension like the above will

To make this optional also not use the Ext, then you need to use the `MatchEvaluator`

Something like this (but I dont have a compiler in front of me, so it might be off by a little and should be tested)

```
Regex.Replace(phone, 
    @"^\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d{2,})$", 
    "+1 $1$2$3-$4$5$6-$7$8$9$10 Ext $11");
     match =>
     {
         var returnVal = "+1 ";
         for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
         {
             returnVal += match.Groups[i].Value;
             if(i == 3 || i == 6)
                 returnVal += "-";
         }
         returnVal += match.Groups[11].Success ? " Ext " + match.Groups[11] : "" )
         return returnVal;
     }
)
```

Comment: @Justin I added on in case the extension is optional. Just thought that might be useful also :)

Comment: Awesome Thanks! Having that is very nice. Is it possible to hide the Ext with the optional so it doesn't look like Ext (blank here)?

Comment: @Justin Updated with a possibility